# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'type' is less accessible than method 'method' in an Interface

Tags: c#, .net

Getting the .net CS0051 error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0051) with consistent interface and classes.

Example code is simplified here in terms of names, but identical in other ways.

--- File 1 ---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace NamespaceOne
    {
    public class ConsentRequest
        {
            public List<SomeOtherPublicObject> Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

--- File 2 ---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace NamespaceTwo
    {
    public class ConsentResponse
        {
            public List<SomeOtherPublicObject> Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

--- File 3 ---

```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using NamespaceOne;
    using NamespaceTwo;
    
    namespace NamespaceThree
    {
        public interface InterfaceOne
        {
            Task<ConsentResponse> UpdateConsent(string a, string b, string c, consentRequest);
            Task<ConsentResponse> UpdateConsent(string b, string c, consentRequest);
        }
    }
```

--- File 4 ---

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using NamespaceOne;
    using NamespaceTwo;
    
    namespace NamespaceFour
    {
        public class ClassOne : InterfaceOne
        {
            public async Task<ConsentResponse> UpdateConsent(string a, string b, string c, consentRequest);
            {
                // code
            }
    
            public async Task<ConsentResponse> UpdateConsent(string b, string c, consentRequest);
            {
                // code
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error for the accessibility of the last parameter in the Interface and the implementation - consentRequest.
I've seen other questions here with regard to methods, but not as a result of the param in the interface and implementation definition when the consentRequest class and all its properties are public.

Actual Errors are:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'NamespaceThree.UpdateConsent(string, string, string, ConsentRequest)' is less accessible than method 'NamespaceFour.UpdateConsent(string, string, string, ConsentRequest)'

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'NamespaceThree.UpdateConsent(string, string, ConsentRequest)' is less accessible than method 'NamespaceFour.UpdateConsent(string, string, ConsentRequest)'

Comment: It would appear that you have simplified this code too much. Please create a proper [mre]. Somehwere, you're missing a `public`, as simple as that.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5ZCVj (after fixing the various syntax errors, which means that you typed this code into the question and haven't tried to run it yourself). Please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve] which demonstrates your issue, in a form that we can run.

Comment: Thank you both.
Built in VS2012 against .NET Framework 4.5 and working for a financial institute, posting the actual code or something reproducible isn't possible. I've looked, and looked and looked again and did find a nested class that wasn't public. Strange because it was compiling 2 days ago and the classes hadn't been touched.
But thanks you both again.
Appreciate your help.